# Python in emacs: __name__ == '__main__', but somehow not

Tags: python, emacs

I am coding python in emacs. However, somehow the python interpreter running in emacs manages to surprise me.

If I write

```
print()
print(__name__)
print(__name__=='__main__')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("indeed")
```

in an emacs buffer, and tell emacs to start an interpreter and run the content of this buffer, I get a buffer containing

```
Python 3.3.5 (default, Mar 18 2014, 02:00:02) 
[GCC 4.2.1 20070831 patched [FreeBSD]] on freebsd9
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
__main__
True
>>>
```

(Both `__main__` and `True` are the outputs from the print statement; the python buffer always displays the `>>>` and prints immediately after it. I am aware of this, this is not a problem.)

From the command line, both `python` and `python -i` show the 'indeed', as expected.

How is Emacs able to the inconsistency of evaluating `__name__=='__main__'` to `True`, while not executing things inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`?
And how do reconfigure it so it does not do so any more?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it's printing the string `"__main__"` as `__main__`...

Comment: @Wooble: ah, the Emacs buffer executed the code straight in a interactive prompt. Gotcha.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in older versions of elpy: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/69 (or, if you're not using elpy, it's a "helpful feature" of python.el.)

Comment: Less confusion like this?

Comment: @Wooble: Oof. That's quite an ugly feature, I think. Also, a valid answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [@Wooble mentioned in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654334/python-in-emacs-name-main-but-somehow-not#comment36330736_23654334), it might be `python.el` issue: `C-c C-c` runs
`python-shell-send-buffer` function:

> python-shell-send-buffer is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `python.el'.
>
> (python-shell-send-buffer &optional ARG)
>
> Send the entire buffer to inferior Python process. With prefix ARG
>   allow execution of code inside blocks delimited by `"if __name__=='__main__':"`

i.e., to print "indeed", add prefix `C-u C-c C-c`.

> **Q:** I have tried to dig through python.el, and I am still not sure how and where it does this. Can you explain, so I can modify the default behaviour?

To find out what `C-c C-c` does in your case open a python file and type `M-x describe-key RET` followed by `C-c C-c` (actually press the keys). By default it runs `python-shell-send-buffer` function in `python.el`. You could redefine the keys to call the function with an argument so that `C-c C-c` would behave like `C-u C-c C-c` that enables running `"if __name__=='__main__':"` part:

```
;; Make C-c C-c behave like C-u C-c C-c in Python mode
(require 'python)
(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c")
  (lambda () (interactive) (python-shell-send-buffer t)))
```

Comment: I have tried to dig through `python.el`, and I am still not sure how and where it does this. Can you explain, so I can modify the default behaviour?

Comment: Lol ok the solution was literally in the docs, I did not expect that. I think I'll see how I can write a `python-shell-send-current-file` function. I think the python-shell should not be used to execute python files. If you have a clue or starting point, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: @sinekonata I often use `M-x compile` to run scripts (prefix C-u allows to set the command).

Answer (score 2):

This 'Feature' gets never old. Try using

```
__name__=='__main__':
```

**without the whitespace between the opperator.**

Then python.el will not bypass it. So look at your code formater.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have started the python shell, you can simply override the variable:

```
__name__ = 'repl'
```

This prevents any `if __name__=='__main__':` blocks from running on any subsequent `C-c C-c` invocations.

Comment: The problem is the opposite: python in emacs *does not* run the “main” blocks from `C-c C-c`. I would even be fine with it overwriting `__name__` internally, but apparently that's not how this happens, as evident from the output. This intransparency is what confuses me.

Comment: @Anaphory: oh! Must have been asleep when reading the question.